# forToWhile on Practice-It

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm currently a beginner in java and while practicing I came across this [practice site](https://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/problem/view/bjp4/chapter5/s2-forToWhile), and I can't quite seem to get part c. I'm supposed to convert the given for loop code into a while loop code, and I'm not sure why my code doesn't print out the exact same thing as the for loop. Any help would really be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Perhaps include expected and actual outputs?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code.

Comment: For future reference, it's easier for others to help you if you post the actual code, rather than a picture of it.  That way, we can copy-paste your code and run it ourselves, to see what's going on.  Generally, pictures of code are not welcome on Stack Overflow.   However, now that you have an answer to your question, it's probably not worth changing it.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem It _is_ worth changing it. For example, for me this image is blocked at work so I don't see that there's an image at all. Chances are high that the question will get downvotes and close votes for seemingly missing code in cases like that. Additionally, users relying on screen readers can't read the code at all. So, jjhh, please edit your question and replace the image with text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need  to move

- `int j = 1;` to inside the first loop, below `while (i <= 2) {`
- `int k = 1;` to inside the second loop, below `while (j <= 3) {`

If you don't do that, then neither of the inner loops will run after the first iteration of the outer loop, because their exit conditions have  already been met.  But resetting the index variables to 1 in both cases allows the inner loops to re-run.